# We are trying to develop a tic-tac-toe game. What algorithm should we use?

Tags: java, algorithm, artificial-intelligence

I know about alpha-beta pruning and the minimax algorithm.
What other algorithms would you suggest?

Is it possible if we use negascout?

Comment: Just parse http://xkcd.com/832/ and store in a moves database. :)

Comment: http://xkcd.com/832/ But seriously, what's wrong with alpha-beta pruning, has it proven too slow? If not, you should try it first and see if it suits you. There's no point in implementing an elaborate algorithm where a simple one will do. Unless of course you're trying to research the algorithm itself.

Comment: "a strange game. The only winning move is not to play."

Comment: @biziclop alpha-beta pruning is widely used. and we are looking for an algorithm that can surpass alphabeta pruning and minimax.

Comment: @ckd1914 Are we talking about an extended tic-tac-toe game here? Because you don't need any of these algorithms for the 3x3 version. You can just store the winning moves.

Comment: You might find the discussion here useful too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125557/what-algorithm-for-a-tic-tac-toe-game-can-i-use-to-determine-the-best-move-for

Answer (score 8):

Considering the simplicity of the game the optimum moves can be simply stored.

Relevant XKCD-
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Tic-Tac-Toe's entire game tree can be represented in memory, so you can just generate that and backtrack winning moves. There are less than 363k legal configurations.