# Algorithm for generalized tic tac toe

Tags: algorithm

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What Algorithm for a Tic-Tac-Toe Game Can I Use To Determine the “Best Move” for the AI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125557/what-algorithm-for-a-tic-tac-toe-game-can-i-use-to-determine-the-best-move-for)

I want to develop a tic tac toe (5x7) game in which there are two players one is computer and one is human.
the player who makes 4 in a row
or 4 in diagonal  first wins. If i do using brute force technique it takes long time for computer to decide next move. Can anyone suggest an algorithm with less time complexity ?
thanks in advance..

Comment: You should use a heuristic in the manner that you would think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Alpha-Beta prunning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alpha-beta_pruning) is a good algorithm for searching for the best next turn.