# Fastest way to generate next move in TIC TAC TOE game

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

In a X's and 0's game (i.e. **TIC TAC TOE(3X3)**) if you write a program for this give a fast way to generate the moves by the computer. I mean this should be the fastest way possible.

All I could think of at that time is to store all the board configurations in a hash so that getting best position of move is a O(1) operation.
Each board square can be either 0,1, or 2.
0 represents empty square. 1 represents a X & 2 represents 0.

So every square can be filled with either of the three. There are approx 3^9 board configurations.

In simple, we need a hash of size 3^9. For hashing,we can go for base 3 representation. Means each number in base 3 will be 9 digits long each digit corresponding to each square.
To search in hash, we need to find the decimal representation of this 9 digit number.
Now, each square can be associated with row number & column number. In order to identify each square uniquely, we can again make use of base 3 representation.
say SQ[1][2] will be 12 in base 3 which is equivalent to 5 in decimal.

Thus, we have effectively designed an algorithm which is fast enough to calculate the next move in O(1).

But, the interviewer insisted in reducing the space complexity as DOS system doesn't have that much amount of memory.

***How can we reduce the space complexity with no change in time complexity?***
Please help me so that I do not miss such type of questions in the future.

Comment: What language are we using here?

Comment: Observe that there's 8-way symmetry?  So in theory, your move table can be stored in 3^9 / 8 / 8 = 308 bytes.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning. I am using C language.

Comment: Hashing the board takes O(n) or O(1) time, depending on whether you extend TTT to arbitrary dimensions.

Comment: @ Oli Charlesworth, can you explain a little more?How the symmetry concept will be used to calculate to positions?Thank you.

Comment: @Aashish: The symmetry means that your lookup table can be 8 times smaller.

Comment: @Aashish: And in fact, there's another factor of 2 you can divide by.  You can swap all Xs with Os, and the results would be the same.  So we're now down to 154 bytes!

Comment: A key question is whether you need to be able to respond to any board situation, or if you're assuming that this computer has played all previous moves for its side.  The point being that you can eliminate board configurations that the computer would never get itself into.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth How did you get 3^9/8/8 bytes?  It sounds like you're trying to store a move in a single bit, which isn't possible.  You need at least 4 bits (3 if you're willing to give up some constant time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a small game like this, a different way of going about this is to pre-compute and store the potential game tree in a table.

Looking first at the situation where the human starts, she obvious has 9 different start positions. A game-play table would contain 9 entry points, then, each pointing to the correct response - you could use the guidelines outlined in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125557/what-algorithm-for-a-tic-tac-toe-game-can-i-use-to-determine-the-best-move-for?rq=1) to calculate the responses - as well as the next level table of human responses. This time there are only 7 possible responses. For the next level there'll be 5, then 3, then just 1. In total, there will be 9 * 7 * 5 * 3 * 1 = 945 entries in the table, but that can be compressed by realizing symmetries, i.e. rotations and flipped colors.

Of course, the situation where the computer starts is similar in principle but the table is actually smaller because the computer will probably want to start by playing the middle piece - or at least avoid certain spots.

Comment: I believe this is the best answer for smallest response time - futhermore, instead of a tree you could use a DAG to save space on repeated positions. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_complexity) says that discounting symmetry there are 5,478 positions.

Answer (score 1):

There are not 3^9 different board configurations. Just as tomdemuyt says, there are 9! different board configurations, i.e., 9 choices at first, 8 choices next, 7 choices after that, and so on.

Also, we can further reduce the space complexity by accounting for symmetry. For example, for the first move, placing an X in [0,0] is the same as placing it in [0,2], [2,0], and [2,2]. I believe this reduces 9! to 9!/4

We can even reduce that by accounting for which board configurations were winning before the final move (the 9th move). I don't know the number, but a detailed explanation can be found on the Stack Overflow cousin http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tic-tac-toe

Comment: Your first paragraph is not correct.  There are at most 9! possible games (at most because many will terminate early).  However, when examining a board configuration, the order that moves were placed is irrelevant.  The original `3^9` estimation is a good upper-bound (again, because some of the boards are inaccessible since the game would end before reaching them; also, because some would contain too many X's or too many O's).

Answer (score 0):

The assumption of 3^9 is wrong. This would include for example a board that only has X which is impossible as both players place each turn an X or an O.

My initial thought was that there are (9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2) * 2 possibilities.
First player has 9 choices, second player has 8 choices, first player has 7 etc.
I put * 2 because you might have different best moves depending who starts.

Now 3^9 is 19863 and 9! is 362880, so clearly this is not the superior solution, a lot of 'different scenarios' actually will end up looking exactly the same. Still, the base idea that many of the 19863 board setups are invalid remain.

This piece of code which probably could be replaced by a simple formula tells me that this is the count of positions you want to have a move for.

```
<script>

a = permuteString( "X........" ); document.write( Object.keys(a).length + "<br>" );console.log( a );
a = permuteString( "XO......." ); document.write( Object.keys(a).length + "<br>" );console.log( a );
a = permuteString( "XOX......" ); document.write( Object.keys(a).length + "<br>" );console.log( a );
a = permuteString( "XOXO....." ); document.write( Object.keys(a).length + "<br>" );console.log( a );
a = permuteString( "XOXOX...." ); document.write( Object.keys(a).length + "<br>" );console.log( a );
a = permuteString( "XOXOXO..." ); document.write( Object.keys(a).length + "<br>" );console.log( a );
a = permuteString( "XOXOXOX.." ); document.write( Object.keys(a).length + "<br>" );console.log( a );

//Subset of the Array.prototype.slice() functionality for a string
function spliceString( s , i )
{
    var a = s.split("");
  a.splice( i , 1 );
    return a.join("");
}

//Permute the possibilities, throw away equivalencies
function permuteString( s )
{
    //Holds result
    var result = {};

    //Sanity
    if( s.length < 2 ) return [];

    //The atomic case, if AB is given return { AB : true , BA : true }
    if( s.length == 2 )
    {
        result[s] = true;
        result[s.charAt(1)+s.charAt(0)] = true;
        return result;
    }

    //Enumerate
    for( var head = 0 ; head < s.length ; head++ )
    {
        var o = permuteString( spliceString( s , head  ) );
        for ( key in o )
            result[ s.charAt( head ) + key ] = true;
    }
    return result;
}


</script>
```

This gives the following numbers:
1st move : 9
2nd move : 72
3rd move : 252
4th move : 756
5th move : 1260
6th move : 1680
7th move : 1260

So in total 5289 moves, this is without even checking for already finished games or symmetry.

These numbers allow you to lookup a move through an array, you can generate this array yourself by looping over all possible games.

T.

Comment: Fewer possibilities than that.  9! is how many possible games you have (ignoring the fact that someone won), but a board does not show the order of the events leading up to that position.  And you don't need to store games where you made suboptimal moves.

Comment: Right, so when you construct the array with the best moves, you skip the scenarios where a player lost. Skipping on suboptimal moves is  trickier.

Comment: It is harder, but it is a one-time affair to figure out what they are and store that state.

Comment: I voted down: 3^9 is obviously a lot smaller than 9!, so your approach is much worse than OP's.

Answer (score 0):

The game of Tic Tac Toe is sufficiently simple that optimal algorithm may be implemented by a machine built from Tinker Toys (a brand of sticks and fasteners).  Since the level of hardware complexity encapsulated by such a construction is below that of a typical 1970's microprocessor, the time required to find out what moves have been made would in most cases exceed the time required to figure out the next move.  Probably the simplest approach would be have a table which, given the presence or absence of markers of a given player (2^9, or 512 entries), would indicate what squares would turn two-in-a-rows into three-in-a-rows.  Start by doing a lookup with the pieces owned by the player on move; if any square which would complete a three-in-a-row is not taken by the opponent, take it.  Otherwise look up the opponent's combination of pieces; any square it turns up that isn't already occupied must be taken.  Otherwise, if the center is available, take it; if only the center is taken, take a corner.  Otherwise take an edge.

It might be more interesting to open up your question to 4x4x4 Tic Tac Toe, since that represents a sufficient level of complexity that 1970's-era computer implementations would often take many seconds per move.  While today's computers are thousands of times faster than e.g. the Atari 2600, the level of computation at least gets beyond trivial.

If one extends the game to 4x4x4, there will be many possibilities for trading off speed, RAM, and code space.  Unlike the original game which has 8 winning lines, the 4x4x4 version has (IIRC) 76.  If one keeps track of each line as being in one of 8 states [ten if one counts wins], and for each vacant square one keeps track of how many of the winning lines that pass through it are in what states, it should be possible to formulate some pretty fast heuristics based upon that information.  It would probably be necessary to use an exhaustive search algorithm to ensure that heuristics would in fact win, but once the heuristics were validated they should be able to run much faster than would an exhaustive search.