# tic tac toe game project image icon?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, imageicon

I am making a tic tac toe project, and i am using the  9 buttons and images(Circle.jpg , Cross.jpg). First of all, i wanna clear one thing to you guys, so first i made this game using letter ("X"), ("O"), now i am using images for this game and also it is computer vs player game
After running, when i clicked on the button it show's me cross on that button, that's right, and computer automatically puts circle in another button!

The problem is that when I click the `Next` button, it shows me a cross, which is correct. But the computer does not put circle to block my row.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TicTacToe implements ActionListener {
/*Instance Variables*/
static int[][] winCombinations = new int[][] {
        {1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}, //horizontal wins
        {1, 4, 7}, {2, 5, 8}, {3, 6, 9}, //vertical wins
        {1, 5, 9}, {3, 5, 7}             //diagonal wins
    };
static JFrame window = new JFrame("Tic-Tac-Toe");
static JButton buttons[] = new JButton[10];
static int count = 0;
static  Icon letter;
static boolean win = false;
static  Icon myImage = new ImageIcon("Cross.jpg"); // 
static  Icon Image = new ImageIcon("Circle.jpg");

static String  AA;
public TicTacToe(){
/*Create Window*/
window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
window.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));

/*Add Buttons To The Window*/
for(int i = 1; i<=9; i++)
{
    buttons[i] = new JButton();
    window.add(buttons[i]);
    buttons[i].setPreferredSize(new Dimension(myImage.getIconWidth(), myImage.getIconHeight()));
    buttons[i].addActionListener(this);
}

/*Make The Window Visible*/
window.setVisible(true);
window.pack();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a) 
{
    /*Write the letter to the button and deactivate it*/
    for(int i = 1; i<= 9; i++){

        if(a.getSource() == buttons[i]){
            buttons[i].setIcon(myImage);
            buttons[i].setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    count++;        
    AI();

}

public void AI(){
    count++;
    if(buttons[1].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[2].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[3].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[3].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
    } else if(buttons[4].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[5].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[6].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[6].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[6].setEnabled(false);
    } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[8].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[9].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[9].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[9].setEnabled(false);                
    } 

    else if(buttons[2].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[3].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[1].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[1].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[5].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[6].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[4].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[4].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[4].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[8].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[9].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[7].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[7].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[7].setEnabled(false);                
    }

    else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[3].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[2].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[2].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[2].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[4].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[6].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[5].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[9].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[8].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[8].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[8].setEnabled(false);                
    }

    else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[4].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[7].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[7].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[7].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[2].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[5].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[8].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[4].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[4].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[3].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[6].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[9].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[9].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[9].setEnabled(false);                
    }

    else if(buttons[4].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[7].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[1].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[1].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[5].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[8].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[2].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[2].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[2].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[6].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[9].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[3].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[3].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[3].setEnabled(false);                
    }

    else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[7].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[4].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[4].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[4].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[2].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[8].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[5].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[3].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[9].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[6].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[6].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[6].setEnabled(false);                
    }

    else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(Image)&& buttons[5].getText().equals(Image)&& buttons[9].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[9].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[9].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[5].getText().equals(Image)&& buttons[9].getText().equals(Image)&& buttons[1].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[1].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(Image)&& buttons[9].getText().equals(Image)&& buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[5].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
    }

    else if(buttons[3].getText().equals(Image)&& buttons[5].getText().equals(Image)&& buttons[7].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[7].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[7].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals(Image)&& buttons[5].getText().equals(Image)&& buttons[3].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[3].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[3].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals(Image)&& buttons[3].getText().equals(Image)&& buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[5].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
    }


    else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[2].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[3].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[3].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[3].setEnabled(false);
    } else if(buttons[4].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[6].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[6].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[6].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[8].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[9].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[9].setEnabled(false);                
    } 

    else if(buttons[2].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[3].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[1].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[1].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[5].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[6].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[4].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[4].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[4].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[8].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[7].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[7].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[7].setEnabled(false);                
    }

    else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[3].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[2].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[2].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[2].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[4].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[6].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[5].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[8].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[8].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[8].setEnabled(false);                
    }

    else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[4].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[7].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[7].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[7].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[2].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[8].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[8].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[8].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[3].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[6].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[9].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[9].setEnabled(false);                
    }

    else if(buttons[4].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[7].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[1].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[1].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[5].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[8].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[2].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[2].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[2].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[6].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[3].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[3].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[3].setEnabled(false);                
    }

    else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[7].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[4].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[4].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[4].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[2].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[8].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[5].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[3].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[6].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[6].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[6].setEnabled(false);                
    }

    else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[9].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[9].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[5].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[1].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[1].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[9].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[5].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
    }

    else if(buttons[3].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[7].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[7].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[7].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[3].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[3].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[3].setEnabled(false);                
    } else if(buttons[7].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[3].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[5].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
    }

    else if(buttons[1].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[9].getText().equals(myImage)) {
        buttons[6].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[6].setEnabled(false);            
    }    

    else if(buttons[3].getText().equals(myImage) && buttons[5].getText().equals(Image) && buttons[7].getText().equals(myImage)) {
        buttons[4].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[4].setEnabled(false);            
    }

    else if(buttons[5].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[5].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[5].setEnabled(false);                
    }

    else if(buttons[1].getText().equals("")){
        buttons[1].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[1].setEnabled(false);                
    }
    else {
        if(count >= 9)
            checkWin();
        else
            RandomMove();
    }

    checkWin();

}

public void RandomMove(){
    Random x = new Random();
    int y = 1 + x.nextInt(9);
    if(buttons[y].getText().equals(Image) || buttons[y].getText().equals(myImage) ){
        RandomMove();
    } else {
        buttons[y].setIcon(Image);
        buttons[y].setEnabled(false);
    }
}

public void checkWin(){ 

    /*Determine who won*/
    for(int i=0; i<=7; i++){
        if( buttons[winCombinations[i][0]].getText().equals(buttons[winCombinations[i][5]].getText()) && 
            buttons[winCombinations[i][6]].getText().equals(buttons[winCombinations[i][7]].getText()) && 
            !buttons[winCombinations[i][0]].getText().equals("")) {
            win = true;
        }
    }

    if(count % 2 == 0)
        letter = Image;
    else
        letter = myImage;

    /*Show a dialog when game is over*/
    if(win == true){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, letter + " wins!");
        System.exit(0);
    } else if(count >= 9 && win == false){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "The game was tie!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    new TicTacToe();
}
```

}

Comment: The question is related to the game logic rather than the GUI. Change the title of the question accordingly.

Comment: What is the exact problem? Wrong programming logic? Or a technical problem of some sort?  Please clarify your exact question and/or problem.

Comment: Check ***[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125557/what-algorithm-for-a-tic-tac-toe-game-can-i-use-to-determine-the-best-move-for)*** post for info on tic-tac-toe algorithms.

Comment: my programming logic is correct, i am pretty sure..but when i used the images to draw circle and cross, than this problem occurred,

Comment: is there any way, that i can show you the images...either give me two vote, i will be able to put images.

Answer (score 1):

this looks wrong to me

```
 buttons[1].getText().equals(Image)
```

you are comparing text with an Image, I doubt that can ever be true.

It should probably be

```
 buttons[1].getIcon() == Image
```

that will only work if you load Image once and use it everywhere as you
are comparing the object reference.